# Region of convergence of the Laplace transform

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, laplace-transform, fourier-transform

Suppose I can show that

\begin{align}\label{eq:1}
\int_0^{\infty}e^{-zx}f(x)\text{d} x = F(z)
\end{align}

holds for all $z$ such that $\Re(z) > b$. Suppose further that $F(z)$ is analytic for all $\Re(z) > a$ and that $b > a$. Can I conclude that the above equality holds also on the larger region $\Re(z) > a$?

Comment: Yes, if, for example, $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-(a+\epsilon)x}|f(x)|dx < \infty$ for all $\epsilon > 0$ because then you have two holomorphic functions that agree on a half space and both of which extended holomorphically to a larger region.

Comment: Thanks! However, I am assuming that (for whatever reason) I can't show that $e^{-cx}f(x)$ is integrable for $a < c < b$. My question is whether the fact that F(z) can be extended to an analytic function for $\Re(z) > a$ somehow implies the integrability of $e^{-cx}f(x)$ on $\Re(z) > a$.

Comment: that should be: implies the integrability of $e^{-zx}f(x)$ on $\Re(z) > a$ and not $e^{-cx}f(x)$ on $\Re(z) > a$